# How do i get the id of a value i immidietly added using dexie js?

Tags: javascript, dexie

How do i access the `id` of an item i already added since the items are occasionally removed the incremented id is not uniform.

I have tried as in the documentation

```
    var db = new Dexie('FRIENDS');
    db.version(1).stores({
    friends: '++id,name,age,loves'
                });
    db.friends.add({
        name: 'user',
        age: 23,
        loves:'water',
    }).then(function(){
         return db.friends.get('user');
    }).then(function (res) {
        console.log(res.id);
    }).catch(function(error) {
             console.log ("Ooops: " + error);
          });

}
```

I get `undifined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct answer is: created id will passed as argument in promise.
Example from documentation:

```js
db.table('todos')
  .add(todo)
  .then((id) => {
    // ...
  });
```

Or returned in async-await style:

```js
const id = await db.table('todo').add(todo);
```

In your example you use wrong syntax of `.get()` method. Correct is:

```js
table.get({keyPath1: value1, keyPath2: value2, ...});
// e.g.
table.get({id: 15})
// or
db.friends.add({
        name: 'user',
        age: 23,
        loves:'water',
    }).then(function(id){
         return db.friends.get({id});
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

*To help anyone else in the future*

**Eventually solved the issue through a hack.**

```
    var db = new Dexie('FRIENDS');
    db.version(1).stores({
    friends: '++id,name,age,loves'
                });
    db.friends.add({
        name: 'user',
        age: 23,
        loves:'water',
    }).then(()=>{
db.friends.each(friend=>{
            window.lastId = { id:friend.id };
        })
.then(()=>{
   console.log(window.lastId.id)
});
});
```